# Need help trying to replicate ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256 in a Rails 6 controller

Tags: ethers.js, keccak, ruby, rails

I'm not super familiar with Ruby or Rails, but I basically need to replicate this Javascript that uses ethersjs and call it from a Rails 6 controller. Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? I've tried several different solutions but none would produce the same result.

```
function hashToken(tokenId, account) {
    return Buffer.from(ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['uint256', 'address'], [tokenId, account]).slice(2), 'hex')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this solution but I was able to produce the right results by just calling a Node script form the Ruby controller. I went ahead and just signed the result from the Node script as well.

Ruby:

```
sig = %x[node app/assets/javascripts/sign.js 1 "0x<REDACTED ADDRESS>"]
```

Nodejs:

```
var ethers = require('ethers')

const tokenID = process.argv[2];
const address = process.argv[3];

let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.WALLET_PK);

function hashToken(tokenId, address) {
    return Buffer.from(ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['uint256', 'address'], [tokenId, address]).slice(2), 'hex')
}

(async () => {
    let sig = await wallet.signMessage(hashToken(tokenID, address));
    console.log(sig);
})()
```